# Class inherit not printing anything

Tags: c#

I have a problem i have inherit a class to print the user info but the result is nothing it just print the space name and the class name that's only!! So could someone till me please what the wrong i have done!! It debag with no issue but it only print this:

Program.Person !!!!!!!!!! ok i create a person in the main and then print this man

and when i add this two line:

input.adjustAge(5);
Console.WriteLine(" the user name adjust his Age by 5: ");

it only print what inside the "" but nothing else!? i am confused..

Here is my Person class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Program
{
    class Person
    {
        private string name;
        private string address;
        private double age;

        public Person()
        {
            this.name = " ";
            this.address = " ";
            this.age = 0.0;
        }
        //non/default constructor
        public Person(string name, string address, double age)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.address = address;
            this.age = age;
            if (age < 0)
                age = 0.0;
        }
        
        public void setName (string name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public string getName()
        {
            return name;
        }
        public void setAddress(string address)
        {
            this.address = address;
        }
        public string getAddress()
        {
            return address;
        }

        public void setAge(double age)
        {
            this.age = age;
        }
        public double getAge()
        {
            return age;
        }

        public void adjustAge(double increment)
        {
            this.age = (this.age + increment);
        }
        

        public string toString()
        {
            string output = " ";
            output += "\nPersons Information: ";
            output += "\nPerson Name:  " + this.name;
            output += "\nPerson Address: " + this.address;
            output += "\nPerson Age: " + this.age;
            
            return output;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my main:

```
using System;

namespace Program
{
    class UsePerson
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Person input = new Person(" Sam ", " 419 West London Rd ", 30);
            Console.WriteLine(input);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Replace `public string toString()` with `public override string ToString()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have not overidden ToString Properly,

Change your toString to following

```
public override string ToString()
{
   string output = " ";
     += "\nPersons Information: ";
   output += "\nPerson Name:  " + this.name;
   output += "\nPerson Address: " + this.address;
   output += "\nPerson Age: " + this.age;
        
   return output;
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method

I would also suggest you to use C# Properties instead of getter and setter methods.